# Angular 2 - How to use config files

Tags: angular

When working in ZF2 we use configuration files that may vary from developer to developer and between production and staging environments. Its pretty convenient and as such I want to replicate this for Angular 2.

How it works in ZF2: We have a config folder with configs named: settings.local.php and settings.global.php. We then use a gitignore file to ignore anything with local in it.

I would like to do something similar with Angular 2 and am not 100% sure of the best method to go about this.

For Angular 2 I was thinking of having a config folder and then using a service to grab the configuration files...

Is there a convention for something like this in Angular 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also come from a ZF2 background and wanted this sort of functionality. I can't promise that this is the 'convention' for achieving this however it works perfectly for me and my situation.

In short I use a combination of JSON config files and [grunt-ng-constant](https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant) (requires [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) obvs..)

My `ngconstant` config in my `Gruntfile.js` looks like this:

```
ngconstant: {
    options: {
        constants: {
            config: grunt.file.readJSON('config/config.global.json')
        },
        name: 'constants',
        dest: 'public/js/src/config.js',
        wrap: '/* global angular */\n\n(function ()\n{\n\t\'use strict\';\n\t\n\t{%= __ngModule %}\n\t\n})();\n'
    },
    dev: {
        constants: {
            config: grunt.file.readJSON('config/config.dev.json')
        }
    },
    live: {
        constants: {
            config: grunt.file.readJSON('config/config.live.json')
        }
    }
}
```

The location of all your files is up to you.. but the theory of this is that `config.global.json` is where all your default configs go. Then depending on whether you run `ngconstant:live` or `ngconstant:dev` it will merge the corresponding config with global and overwrite any overlaps.

This saves the config to a new Angular `constant`, `public/js/src/config.js`, which I can then inject into any service / controller that I want.

```
/**
 * My Controller
 */
angular
    .module('ctrls')
    .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

/**
 * @param $scope
 * @param config
 */
function myCtrl($scope, config)
{
    $scope.someConfig = config.someConfigValue;
}
```