# How can I set Angular values from a config file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app that I have inherited that I have to support. So far it had only run on one server and we want to run it on different servers. We found hard coded references to the server name all over the place in python server code and C++ client code. It was easy enough to change those to read the server name from a config file. But now I find is a js module this code:

```
angular.module('app.config', []).constant('config', {"api":"http://foo.bar.com:8001/"});
```

How can I change this so that the value for the server is read dynamically from a config file or some other means that would not require it to be hard coded?

Here is an update with what I have tried:

Originally, my code had this:

```
angular.module('app.config', []).constant(
  'config', {"api":"http://foo.bar.com:8001/"}
);
```

and I changed it to this:

```
angular.module('app.config').controller('myCtrl', 
  function($scope, $http) { 
    $http.get('./config.json') 
      .then(function(response) { 
        $scope.api = response.data; 
    }); 
});
```

and I got this:

```
error Module 'app.config' is not available!
```

Then I changed it to:

```
angular.module('app.config', [] ).controller('myCtrl', 
  function($scope, $http) { 
    $http.get('./config.json') 
      .then(function(response) { 
        $scope.api = response.data; 
      }); 
});
```

And then I get:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: configProvider <- config <- workitem
```

I feel I am very close, I just need a bit more help.

Another update:

I tried this:

```
angular.module('app').controller('home', ['$scope', homeCtrl]);
angular.module('app').controller('workitem', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$sce', '$timeout', '$http', 'config', workitemCtrl]);
},{"./home/home.js":3,"./workitem/workitem.js":4,"angular":10,"angular-route":6,"angular-sanitize":8,"bootstrap-treeview/src/js/bootstrap-treeview.js":11}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
  module.exports = function($scope,$http) {
      $http.get('config.json').success(function(reponse) {
          console.log("reponse --> "+reponse.api);
          $scope.api = reponse.api;
      });
  }
```

But then of course app.config was not getting defined. How could I do this an still define app.config?

I just tried this:

```
var my_config = {};

$.getJSON("config.json", function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    my_config[key] = val;
  });
});
```

but I get my_config is not defined when I use it down in the controller. How can I make that variable available in the controller?

Comment: do you mean a separate .json file?

Comment: Are you using a build tool like grunt or gulp??

Comment: Separate from what? The config file I am using for our python and C++ code is simple key values pairs. I'd like to use the same file for this as well.

Comment: if you use some builder like grunt you can easily pass it a Json configuration file, and have the build tool replace placeholder strings in the JS with values from said conf file

Comment: No we are not using any build tools. That would probably be overkill for us - right now we just want to deploy on 2 hosts. Maybe a few more down the road, but all in house. I just don't want to have a different js file for each host.

Comment: Like I posted in the answer, the best way to do this is wrap the dynamic reading in an angular service and save the url in localStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get this working by doing this up front:

```
angular.module('app').value('config', {
  api: ''
});

angular.module('app').run(function($rootScope, $http, config) {
  $http.get('config/config.json').then(function(response) {
        config.api = response.data.api;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('config-loaded');
    });
});
```

Wrapping the main code in:

```
var init = function(){
}
```

And adding this at the end:

```
if (config.api) {
  init()
} else {
    var configLoaded = scope.$on('config-loaded', function() {
        init();
        configLoaded();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This

```
angular.module('app.config', [])
.constant('bbConfig',{ 
     "api":"http://foo.bar.com:8001/"
 });
```

In controller

```
angular.module('app.config', [])
.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope', 'bbConfig' , function ($scope, bbConfig){
    console.log(bbConfig.api)
}]);
```

Comment: I like this solution because this file now becomes just a normal config file. In other words, it stops living in the release and is instead managed in each instance it is deployed.

Comment: Where would I put the code in the first block? In a file? Where is that file referenced?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

1. Use **ngConstant** build task to wrap your standalone config file in JSON format into the includable angular.config data.
   Suppose you have `app/config.json` file:

   {
     "myFirstCnt": true,
     "mySecondCnt": { "hello": "world" }
   }

Then after running the ngConstant task in you build you'll get dist/config.js (output) will be :

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
  return angular.module("my.module.config", ["ngAnimate"])
    .constant("myFirstCnt", true)
    .constant("mySecondCnt", { "hello": "world" })
    .constant("myPropCnt", "hola!");
});
```

[Gulp plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-constant), [Grunt plugin](https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant), [more on ngConstant](http://mindthecode.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-your-angular-application/)

2. Use service to load the JSON file immediately after you app bootstraps in service or in the controller:

should avoid this:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', 
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('PATH_TO/config.json').then(function(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    });
  }
);
```

More on that way example here: [Reading in JSON through Angular Resources Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849902/reading-in-json-through-angular-resources-service)

**UPD 12-06**

For parsing loaded JSON try this:

```
for (var name in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(var)) {
     my_config[var] = data[var];
  }
}
```

Comment: [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766348/angular-2-how-to-use-config-files/36766722#36766722) on this method.

Comment: @Ankh, that one is about AngularJS 2.x version, while here it's 1.x

Comment: When I used `app.controller` I got an error. I changed it to this: `angular.module('app').controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) { $http.get('./config.json') .then(function(response) { $scope.api = response.data; }); });` and now later in the script when app.config is referenced I get the error `Module 'app.config' is not available!`

Comment: you should reference **$scope.api** as you pass data to it in that code line: $scope.api = response.data; or change the naming onto $rootScope.api, then it will be available in all controllers

Comment: Guess I am not understanding what I need to do. I changed all the references to `$scope.config.api` to `$scope.api` but I get the same error. Also tried changing the assignment to`$rootScope.api = response.data` and got the same error.

Comment: Also tried changing it to `angular.module('app.config').controller(...` but still same error.

Comment: @shershen I have updated my post with more details on what I have tried and the errors I got. if you can give me any more advise I would really appreciate it.

Comment: ok. can you put all your angular application code into the files in plunkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) OR commit to some GitHub repository and provide a link - then we can look what's exactly going wrong

Comment: There is just one file. Our code is only 134 lines, but the file is over 32K lines. I think all of Angular is part of the file. IDK, I didn't write this it was just dumped in my lap. I tried to paste the entire file, but it won't save it, probably because it's too big. So I deleted everything below our code. I hope it is still useful to you. The one and only thing I want to change is on lines 42-43 - I want to set api from a JSON file and not have it hard coded. Thanks very much.

http://plnkr.co/edit/iKbyPZII2VD9ItIk8Ex4?p=catalogue

Comment: if you're using this require loader (see 3 minified lines on top of the file), and you have all the app in one file (is that true? that's important) - why not to include it just like **var MYCONFIGS = require('./config.json');** on line 10; then just reference it in your controllers or other places - **MYCONFIGS. api** or **MYCONFIGS.some_other_property**; this will work if the file is root of the app folder

Comment: It does not find the config file. I put it in the dir that the root is set to in the nginx config. I get `Cannot find module` The other js files in require lines are in the same file. One resolves to line 44 and the other to line 66. The more I look at this the less I understand it.

Comment: Made another update. Tried it with `getJSON` - it works, but I can't access the variable I load the JSON into down in the controller.

Comment: I was finally able to get this working. I had to make a few changes in my code. I will create an answer with the details. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service to read the config (json file) or make a call to server and store the response URL in LocalStorage like the following. You can access it from every where

$localStorage.api = response.Url ; // http://foo.bar.com:8001/