# Get ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT from within Angular

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular, asp.net-core

I'm building an application with Angular with a .NET core backend. I have set an environment variable in both Angular and .NET.

And I'm wondering, is there a way to get the .NET's "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" variable from Angular?

Answer (score 1):

Expose an API that returns the current environment name. You can then use it from your Angular App.

**Update:**

1. Define your environment variable in `appsettings.json` (preferably in a json config file of it's own).
2. Set the ASP.NET CORE app to use it. [Steps from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration).
3. You can now use the contents of that file as constants in your app using a method [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36766722). You may of course replace grunt with gulp ([gulp-ng-constant](https://github.com/guzart/gulp-ng-constant)) if you'd prefer. (I haven't tried this step, but I'd be happy to help).

Build events are supported. So if you use environment variables you can generate a config file on the fly (via build events) and your angular app can then access that as mentioned in step 3 above.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping not to do this and reading the environment from a config on the machine.

Comment: @MikeBovenlander This was possible in the classic asp.net web api apps via build tasks. Not quite sure if the new csproj format supports it.

Comment: @MikeBovenlander I've updated the answer! Hope it helps. If you manage to find a solution better than mine, don't forget to answer your question, because I'm quite interested in this myself.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'm not there yet but I think I can use your update as a handle. Ill dive back in this weekend and will keep you posted.